# Extract values in one line based on key json decode and foreach

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I need to work out how i can get showBtn(3) to match up against the first result in every other key.

```
ShowBtn/3 
btnMenulink/101 
btnArticleLink/2 
btnPhone/036244789 
btnUrl/ 
btnName/Office
```

PHP:

```
$jsonresult = '{"showBtn":["3","3"],"btnMenuLink":["101","101"],"btnArticleLink":["2","2"],"btnPhone":["036244789","0404256478"],"btnURL":["",""],"btnName":["Office","Mobile"]}';

$array      = json_decode($jsonresult,true);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $next_key => $next_value) { 
        echo $key . ":" . $next_key . ":" . $next_value . "\n";
    }
}
```

I want this:

```
if (showBtn == 3) {

    echo '<a href='tel:btnPhone'>btnName</a>';

}
```

the result would be

```
<a href="tel:036244789">Office</a> <a href="tel:0404256478">Mobile</a>
```

I almost have it!

```
$jsonresult = '{"showBtn":["3","3"],"btnMenuLink":["101","101"],"btnArticleLink":["2","2"],"btnPhone":["036244789","0404256478"],"btnURL":["",""],"btnName":["Office","Mobile"]}';

$parsed     = json_decode($jsonresult,true);

echo 'Showbtn: '.$parsed['showBtn'][0].' Phone: '.$parsed['btnPhone'][0].' Name: '.$parsed['btnName'][0];
echo '<hr/>Showbtn: '.$parsed['showBtn'][1].' Phone: '.$parsed['btnPhone'][1].' Name: '.$parsed['btnName'][1];
```

Now i just gotta get that [0] [1] into the loop somehow

I have it but can it be done better?

```
$jsonresult = '{"showBtn":["3","3"],"btnMenuLink":["101","101"],"btnArticleLink":["2","2"],"btnPhone":["036244789","0404256478"],"btnURL":["",""],"btnName":["Office","Mobile"]}';

$parsed          =   json_decode($jsonresult,true);

$i=0;

foreach ($parsed as $key => $value) {

    if ($parsed['showBtn'][$i] == 3) {

       echo 'Showbtn: '.$parsed['showBtn'][$i].' Phone: '.$parsed['btnPhone'][$i].' Name: '.$parsed['btnName'][$i].'<hr/>';   

    }
    $i++;  
}
```

Comment: does it every time showBtn":["3","3"] or count and value may be different?

Comment: @splash58 the 3,3 values will always be 3 because thats phone button choice. But there could be 3,3,1. The user is choosing to add two hone buttons and one menu button link. I have added more to my post again. I have it worked out finally! but can it be done better?

Comment: I wanted to offer the same algorithm :)

Answer (score 1):

This'll work for you. You need to work it as this way

```
$jsonresult = '{"showBtn":["3","3"],"btnMenuLink":["101","101"],"btnArticleLink":["2","2"],"btnPhone":["036244789","0404256478"],"btnURL":["",""],"btnName":["Office","Mobile"]}';

$array = json_decode($jsonresult,true);

foreach($array['showBtn'] as $key => $value){   
    if($value == 3){
        echo '<a href="tel:'.$array['btnPhone'][$key].'">'.$array['btnName'][$key].'</a><br>';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Office
Mobile
```

Comment: I have it worked out, yours looks good. I think it looks like it focuses on showBtn as the carrying factor? I will test it as it is probably cleaner than mine?

Comment: for some reason it wont work > i remeber trying to add this into teh foreach a few times but with no luck. Why will it not work your way?

Comment: If `showBtn` has `3` values then each variable within your json will be having 3 values or not

Comment: @JohnRama You have to do it my way your code won't work try to `print_r($value)` within your `foreach` loop you can identify your problem

Comment: showBtn value of 3 is the choice for phone button. There happens to be 2 buttons with phone numbers in there. showBtn can look like this 1,2,3,3 - That would mean all others have 4 entries. Total of 4 buttons with the last two as tel: phone buttons. I have it working above inside my question but is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Check [this link](https://eval.in/330239) what your code outputs. If your each variables have equal number of values then my code'll work surely

Comment: thats good but you changed your code from $array['showBtn'] to $arry inside the foreach. I will try that now

Comment: the $value in your code is an array in itself. I cant get 3 out of the value.

Comment: The code didnt work like that either - from your linekd example

Comment: Its working for me check my updated answer @JohnRama Check [this link](https://eval.in/330339)